# Post data to laravel through React

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, api

I'm trying to register user through React form, pass the values to controller in Laravel and insert into the database.The problem is, then I press submit button, in the console I get the error:

> POST ('localhost:3001/api/register') 404 NOT FOUND

There is my api.php file

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::post('register','Auth\RegisterController@create');
```

RegisterForm.js

```
import { addUser } from './RegisterFunctions';

...

onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    addUser(this.state.name, this.state.email, this.state.password).then(() => {
      this.getAll();
    });
    this.setState({
      name: '',
      email: '',
      password: ''
    });
  };
...
```

and RegisterFunctions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';


export const addUser = (name, email, password) => {
    return axios
        .post('/api/register',
            {
                name:name,
                email:email,
                password:password
            },
            {
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
};
```

Also, I defining proxy in package.json.
What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: i think you need to give full path to axios.post(baseurl/api/register)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specified base url in question. Console log shows full path, but it's says that page is not found

Comment: are you able to hit it through postman ?

Comment: Yes, it works with postman

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making request to the wrong endpoint 
Change your baseUrl to

```
localhost:portNumber // port that your php server is running on
```

Hope it helps

Comment: in Laravel project I set in .env file like that:
`APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
REACT_APP_BASE_URL = http://localhost:3001`

And in react project I tried set in config.json:
`{ 
"baseUrl": "http://localhost:3001" //also tried with 8000 port
}`

and in tsconfig.json with:
`"baseUrl" : "localhost:3001" // also tried with 8000 port`